# How to integrate $\int_1^e \ln{x} \, dx$

Tags: integration

This seems really tricky to me. I can't figure out how to integrate $\ln x$.

Comment: Try to look it up in some integration table. That would help.

Comment: Integrate $1\cdot\ln x$ by parts ;)

Comment: @HuiYu not if this is homework or some other assignment

Comment: @CBenni Oh, yeah...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based upon geometrical observation we write that

$$\int_1^e \ln x\space \mathrm{dx}=e-\int_0^1 e^x\space \mathrm{dx}=1$$

The question may also be viewed as a particular case of [Young's inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/YoungsInequality.html).

Comment: That is MUCH nicer (IMHO) then the regular integration by parts trick!

Comment: @AmihaiZivan: thanks! :-)

Comment: @Chris'ssister I wonder what did you do here? Can you please explain?

Comment: @weasel: I simply used the inverse function of $\ln x$. Make a drawing and see what happens in the rectangle $[1, e] \times [0, 1]$ if you employ the inverse function.

Comment: Thank you. I learned a new method, here.

Answer (score 7):

*Hint* Integration by parts is helpful.

Let $u=$ln$x$ , $dv=1dx$ 
so $du=\frac{1}{x} dx$ , $v=x$

so that $uv$ - $\int_{1}^{e}vdu$ = $x$ln$x \mid_{1}^{e}- \int_{1}^{e} dx$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int\ln x\,dx=\int u\,dx = xu-\int x\,du = x\ln x - \int x\left(\frac1x\,dx\right).
$$
Now here's the hard part: $x\cdot\dfrac1x$ simplifies to $1$.  At least, I've seen lots of students get stuck on that part.  Some of them want to antidifferentiate $x$ and also $\dfrac1x$.

So you've got
$$
x\ln x-\int 1\,dx.
$$
You can probably do the rest.

Comment: (+1) I remember somewhere some answer was upvoted for the humour in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change variable formula $ \int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f (x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(\varphi(u))\varphi^\prime (u) du$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{e}\ln (x)\, dx =
&
\int_{e^{0}}^{e^{1}}\ln (x) \, dx \\
=
&
\int_0^1\ln( e^u ) (e^u)^\prime du \\
=
&
\int_0^1 u \cdot e^u du \\
\end{align}
Now use integration by parts.

Comment: And what is u here?

Comment: Reminds me of my favorite 0=1 proof! Let's do $\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x}dx$ by partial integration! 
$\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{1}{x}\cdot x -\int_{}^{}x d\frac{1}{x}=1+\int_{}^{}\frac{x}{x^2}dx=1+\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x}dx$
Apparently $\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x}dx=1+\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x}dx$$$


Therefore $0=1$
I always tell my students that finding the error helps to understand integration by parts. I learned this proof 50 years ago. It is still fun!